# how to use StandardEnvironment in a plan java application ,not in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I read spring source code,I find the class StandardEnvironment . I want to use StandardEnvironment in a plan java application as follows。 But It is wrong. Can you help me ?

java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test(com.dominos.cloud.user.dao.EnvimentTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.dominos.cloud.user.dao.EnvimentTest,fLeadingIdentifier=test]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@2acf57e3 at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464) at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)

```
public class EnvimentTest {


    @Test
    public void test() {

         StandardEnvironment enviment=new StandardEnvironment();
                System.out.println(enviment.getProperty("Pk")==null?"not value":enviment.getProperty("Pk"));


    }
}
```

Comment: `Environment` is pretty much bound into tons of Spring concepts (it cares about profiles and resolves properties). Why would you want to use that specific class in a non-Spring environment? What are you trying to do, this smells like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: The error is in your test... Make sure you are using the proper `@Test` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use [StandartEnvironment](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/StandardEnvironment.html) without having Spring, it is part of spring.

What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to use some kind of properties in a plain java application? What about using [java.lang.System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) and its method getProperty? Do you think you can pass the needed arguments on startup of the java? ...like adding -DmyProperty=propertyValue

Another way that might be useful for you to look at is [java.lang.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html). You can create a properties object and load the data from an InputStream (for example from file).

If you need to support different sets of the properties for different runs of your java plain app, then you can combine both approaches and give as a system parameter the name of the file from where all the properties needs to be read.

Was this helpful to you?